# Android checkable menu item resets on orientation change

Tags: android, menuitem, android-orientation, android-optionsmenu

I have a checkable `MenuItem`in my application. I check for the last state and change its icon according to the pervious state (when app restarts or ...). The problem is, when the device orientation changes, these methods that I have below does not work!

I wonder if it is my code or there is a special case when orientation changes and the menu items get reset?

It is defined in the xml file like so:

So the above is the default behavior that I want, that is when the application installs on the phone it's first statee should be `false`.

In the activity, I have in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` the following code, which will check the state and changes the icon before showing the menu to user:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_toggle_logging);

    if (item.isChecked()) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
    } else {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And here is in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_toggle_logging:
            if (item.isChecked()) {
                getApplicationReference().stopLoggerService(); //stop stuff
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            } else {
                getApplicationReference().startLoggerService(); //start stuff
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
            }
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist local members to a bundle. This lets them survive configuration changes (like orientation changes).

```
private static final String LOGGGING_KEY = "logging-key";
private boolean mLoggingOn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mLoggingOn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(LOGGGING_KEY, false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(LOGGGING_KEY, mLoggingOn);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```